# How to calculate Arc Cosine, without a unit circle.

Tags: trigonometry

How can I calculate the $\arccos(Y)$, neither using the trig functions on a calculator, nor using a unit circle?

I would be satisfied if I got $\arcsin(Y)$ or $\arctan(Y)$ instead, but I would prefer $\arccos(Y)$?

Comment: You could use a Padé approximant.

Comment: it would also be nice to do this without mathematics.

Comment: My goal is to do it using only math that does not require already knowing Arc; (sin, cos, tan, or 1 divided by those 3)